# Find the equation of the curve

Tags: calculus

I've been given the following math question; however, I don't understand the wording of what it's asking.

if $ \dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} = y''= \dfrac{dy'}{dx} = 3x^2 + x $ for any point on a curve and the tangent line at $ (1,-2) $ is $ y = 2 - 4x $, find the equation of the curve.

Comment: You have an explicit second order differential equation. Can you not integrate it?

Comment: Follow Lowman's advice. And then integrate again. Then note that you have an IVP; that is $y'(1) = -4$ and $y(1) = -2$.

Comment: I edited the question to add a missing part. y' = x^3 + (1/2)x^2+c

Comment: You're missing the constant of integration in $y'$.

Comment: I know that y = (1/4)x^4+1x^3+cx. I don't know what to do next to get the equation of the curve though.

Comment: You should have a second constant of integration, i.e., $y=\frac14 x^4 +\frac 16 x^2+c_1x+ c_2$

Comment: I know how to integrate, I just don't know how to find the equation of the curve given the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We integrate $y''$ to get $y'$. So, $y'=x^3+\frac{1}{2}x^2+c_{1}$, where $c_{1}$ is the constant of integration (to be found).

Recall that $y'$ is the "slope function", $m$, of the tangent line. In this case, $m=-4$. That is, $y'(x=1)=-4$. We use this condition to find the value of $c_{1}$: $$y'(1)=1+\frac{1}{2}+c_{1}=-4\quad\Rightarrow\quad c_{1}=-\frac{11}{2}$$

So, $y'=x^3+\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{11}{2}$. Now integrate $y'$ to get $y$ (which is the equation of the curve). So, $y=\frac{1}{4}x^4+\frac{1}{6}x^3-\frac{11}{2}x+c_{2}$, where $c_{2}$ is the constant of integration (to be found).

Recall that we have a point that lies on the curve, namely, $(x,y)=(1,-2)$. This means that $y(x=1)=-2$. So, $$y(1)=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}-\frac{11}{2}+c_{2}=-2\quad\Rightarrow\quad c_{2}=\frac{37}{12}$$

So, $y=\frac{1}{4}x^4+\frac{1}{6}x^3-\frac{11}{2}x+\frac{37}{12}$.